# How to find average of seconds in php

Tags: php

i am displaying some pictures in iphone app.If user view the picture information,i am storing total seconds the user viewed into mysql table.Now how can find average of seconds for each picture.

Comment: What photo in what context exactly? Please give more detailed information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do this in PHP. You can get the database to do the work by using the [`AVG`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) aggregate function:

```
SELECT AVG(seconds_viewed) AS avg_seconds_viewed
FROM yourtable
WHERE id = 123
```